# Inject theme props with Theme provider in a external packages

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, material-ui, rollupjs

I want to structure my react project linking my custom `@material-ui` components in an external dependency, I'm using rollup to made it. Building my external dependency and publishing it on npm all work correctly. I can import on my project and `Theme provider` provide the theme props on the external components.

Now to improve the development process on the external dependency I would link my project with my external library, I tried to use `yarn link`, it seems that the components are linked correctly but they don't receive the theme props to styled the components.

On below an example of the structure of my external components:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root:{
      padding: 20,
    },
    subtitle:{
      margin:'12px 0',
      color: theme.palette.gray.dark
    }
}));

function ExampleLayout(props){
  const classes = useStyles(props);

  return(
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

It not find the color: theme.palette.gray.dark (theme is undefined) (Palette and others configuration are correct because if I build and publish all works), the problems is that external components contained on ThemeProvider not receive the theme props;

Anyone knows if is a problem with theme provider or something else?

Your Environment 
Tech    Version
Material-UI v4.9.8
React   v16.9.0
Browser Chrome
TypeScript  no
Rollup  1.27.2
etc.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to solve this? I keep geting my theme color is undefined when importing the theme from another repository :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `theme.palette.grey['500']` for example, or any of the keys:

```
50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, A100, A200, A400, A700
```

Which basically gives you an option to easily control the HUE of the color.

In your code it would be:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root:{
      padding: 20,
    },
    subtitle:{
      margin:'12px 0',
      color: theme.palette.grey["50"]
    }
}));
```

> Note the typo in gray->grey

More on palettes and colors in MUI you can find here: https://material-ui.com/customization/color/

Comment: I know, the problem is not the var "dark", is the theme that is undefined. Seems that makeStyles not receive the theme.

Comment: @ManoloBattista I don't see any issue that you refer to. Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-kare-17yze

Comment: I just solved it, I had a wrong configuration on my rollup, I have to define that material-ui is a "external" dependency in this way the singleton makeStyle of  material is correctly import on my external components (without external it create multiple instances). Moreove I have to set an alias for material on my main application using webpack. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @ManoloBattista could you share the changes you made to fix this. I am observing same issue.

Comment: I write to you in a new answer